# How do I configure shared folders for VirtualBox on Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am trying to use VirtualBox to set up a multi-host software testing environment. I need to share code and data between the VM and host computer (Ubuntu Linux in both cases). Using the "Shared Folders" menu item from VirtualBox does not seem to enable folder sharing as desired.

How do I properly configure shared folders between the host and the VM?

Comment: Wrong site, not a coding question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not already done so, make sure the VirtualBox Guest Additions are already installed (top
menu -> Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD, then follow the prompts)

On the host, go to VirtualBox window:

> top menu -> Devices -> Shared Folders -> Shared Folder Settings

Click "+" icon on right:

- Under "Folder Path" navigate to an absolute pathname on the host like "/home/joe/myFolder"
- Under "Folder Name" enter a unique ID like "someName"

On guest VM, open a terminal and type:

```
> sudo mkdir -p /mystuff
> sudo mount -t vboxsf someName /mystuff
```

The trick is that the ID string "someName" is just a tag to connect the host directory and the VM
directory.  It has not other purpose. The shared folder /home/joe/myFolder is now available as the dir /mystuff in the VM. Note
that the directory name in the VM doesn't have to match the original directory name on the host, although we could make them similar if we wanted (e.g. `/myfolder` or `/joe/myFolder` in the VM).

The VirtualBox GUI does not make a clear distinction between the directory name on the host, the directory
name on the VM, and the ID string that connects them.

Answer (score 1):

Open your VM And go to the top menu Device and click on Insert Guest Additions CD

[image]

Now go to the VM setting and follow the settings

[image]

Folder path, you locate your share folder. After that give a Folder name

Now again go to in your VM terminal

and type the following command

$ sudo /media//VBox_GAs6.0.12/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

$ mkdir /home//shared

$ sudo mount -t vboxsf ubuntushare /home//shared